# converting k and M to thousands and millions using mutate across and an ifelse statement

Tags: r

I have some data which looks like:

```
   col1  col2  col3
1  1.3M 1.31M 2.20M
2 1.47k   20k  2.2M
3  900k  999k   37M
```

I can use the following:

```
dat %>% 
  mutate(across(contains("col"), ~ifelse(grepl('k$',.), gsub('k','000',.),
                                                            ifelse(grepl('M$',.),gsub('M','00000',.),.)))) %>% 
  mutate(across(contains("col"), ~str_remove_all(., '\\.')))
```

Which gives me:

```
     col1     col2     col3
1 1300000 13100000 22000000
2  147000    20000  2200000
3  900000   999000  3700000
```

However, this is "wrong".

In `col1` row1, it produces the correct output 1,300,000 (1.3M) but `col2` row2 gives a wrong answer 13,100,000 ( should be 1.31M ).

I am trying to use `str_pad()` in the same `ifelse` but cannot seem to get it working.

I want to convert all of the `k` to thousands and all of the `M` to millions but just adding 0's on the end gives inconsistent restuls.

Data:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  col1 = c('1.3M', '1.47k', '900k'),
  col2 = c('1.31M', '20k', '999k'),
  col3 = c('2.20M', '2.2M', '37M')
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: if you account for the string size you can decide how many 0's to append on to your data. in the example below all I am doing is adding an additional condition to the ifelse statement where if it is a length of 4 and contains 'M' append 5 0's else append 4 0's. You can add more ifelse statements to decided how many 0's to add on.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <- data.frame(
  col1 = c('1.3M', '1.47k', '900k'),
  col2 = c('1.31M', '20k', '999k'),
  col3 = c('2.20M', '2.2M', '37M')
)


dat %>% 
  mutate(across(contains("col"), ~ifelse(grepl('k$',.), gsub('k','000',.),
                                         ifelse(grepl('M$',.) & nchar(.) ==4,gsub('M','00000',.),gsub('M','0000',.))))) %>% 
  mutate(across(contains("col"), ~str_remove_all(., '\\.')))
```

Edit:
This might be a cleaner way of doing the same thing (and more dynamic). I would just remove the K and M and then multiply by a 1000 or a 1000000 to get the full number.

```
dat %>% 
  mutate(across(contains("col"), ~ifelse(grepl('k$',.), as.numeric(gsub('k','',.))*1000,
                                  ifelse(grepl('M$',.) ,as.numeric(gsub('M','',.))*1000000,.))))
```

Comment: Should I add `nchar(.) ==3` for the `k` part of the `ifelse` statement also?

Comment: hmm I think that would be ok but for 1.47k do you want that to be 1470 or 147000?

Comment: No, I am wrong. I just checked my data and they round to the nearest `k` - so only the millions get 2 decimal places (the `k`'s only get 1 decimal place)..

Comment: ok no worries check the edit to see if it is more dynamic for you

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to be dependent on extra packages, here is a base R method.

```
dat <- data.frame(
col1 = c('1.3M', '1.47k', '900k'),
col2 = c('1.31M', '20k', '999k'),
col3 = c('2.20M', '2.2M', '37M')
)

dat_num = apply(dat, 2, function(i) as.numeric(gsub('(\\d+)\\w', '\\1', i)))
dat_text = apply(dat, 2, function(i) gsub('.*([kM]$)', '\\1', i))

for(i in 1:ncol(dat)){
    for(j in 1:nrow(dat)){
        tmp = dat_text[i, j]
        if(tmp == 'k') dat_num[i, j] = dat_num[i, j] * 1000
        if(tmp == 'M') dat_num[i, j] = dat_num[i, j] * 1e6
    }
}
```

[image]